# Delete folders except one folder in windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder

- C:\apache
- C:\apache112
- C:\apache234

I have batch script to delete folder apache (with wildcards) in drive C.

```
forfiles /p C:\ /m *apache* /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rd /s /q @file"
```

How to delete folder apache (with wildcards) in drive C **except folder c:\apache**?

Comment: No need to use `FORFILES` to accomplish this task. It creates a lot of overhead. You can use just a normal `FOR` command with the `/D` and `/R` options.

Comment: @Squashman, no need for `/R`, but for the rest you're absolutely right...

Comment: @aschipfl, can you give me a complete command?

Comment: `for /D %%I in ("C:\*apache*") do if /I not "%%~nxI"=="apache" rd /S /Q "%%~I"`?

Comment: @aschipfl, works like magic, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to change your pattern to:

```
apache?*
```

That should match anything starting with `apache` and followed by at least one character.

Comment: Usually the `?` matches zero one characters when at the end like you did, but since `forfiles` treats wildcards differently than almost all other commands, I'm in doubt; a pity that I can't test at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Unless absolutely necessary (e. g., due to its `/D` option), avoid `forfiles`, because it is slow and it behaves differently than most other commands with respect to wildcards. Use a standard [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) instead, like this:

```cmd
rem // Loop through all matching directory:
for /D %%I in ("*apache*") do (
    rem // Utilise a condition for exclusion:
    if /I not "%%~nxI"=="apache" (
        rem // Actually remove the directory, if applicable:
        rd /S /Q "%%~I"
    )
)
```